# .net Owin Self host with with no caching

Tags: .net, signalr, owin

I have a OWIN self-host application, to provide a simple development web server for serving up a single-page HTML application. Since I edit the javascript externally, I want to tell the server to send back cache headers that expire immediately (to keep Chrome from caching).

What do I need to add to my startup (note that this server has file browsing enabled).

```
   class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = (Tools.DebugLevel > 10);
            hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            //app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
            {
                //RequestPath = new PathString("/Scopes"),
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
                FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\Scopes"),
            });
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got some help in the microsoft asp forums:

https://forums.asp.net/p/2094446/6052100.aspx?p=True&t=635990766291814480

Here is what I do and it works great: I added the following line to the Startup:

```
app.Use(typeof(MiddleWare));
```

...

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = (Tools.DebugLevel > 10);
        hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        //app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.Use(typeof(MiddleWare));
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            //RequestPath = new PathString("/Scopes"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\Scopes"),
        });
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
    }
}
```

and then I defined my middleware:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gateway
{
    class MiddleWare : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public MiddleWare(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
        {
        }
        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
            context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: setting Expires header to 0 throws an exception that its not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than a new middleware is to use the `StaticFileOptions` within `FileServerOptions` like this

```
options.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = context =>
{
     context.OwinContext.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
     context.OwinContext.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
     context.OwinContext.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
};
```